# Add assignee to web UI (at Change Info section)

Tags: gerrit

I running Gerrit 3.5.0.1,

I added the folloing lines to gerrit.conf

```
[cache]
    enableAssignee = true
```

then I saw the assignee at change log but not at change info.

anyone know how to add it there?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The correct is "change" instead of "cache":

```
[change]
    enableAssignee = true
```

See more info at Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#change).